# PHP Long Polling Script Not Ending

Tags: php, ajax, long-polling

I have searched far and wide for a working answer and despite no shortage of questions on this issue, have not yet found one.

I have a php script which checks the db for updates initiated by an ajax call with setTimeout. The page is like a game lobby where users can create, join or leave a game. When they do, the listening ajax function is aborted while the update occurs and then resumes straight after. This works perfectly with no delays or lag when I test it as a solo user but as soon as another user is on the page, the php script seems to hang up and not want to exit out of the loop, with nothing happening on the front end until it has timed out.

I have added session_write_close, ob_flush and flush(), tried it with and without session_start, all to no avail. I'm sure websockets are better suited but they are currently not an option.

**AJAX**

```
var hear,
    checking;
function listen(){
    hear = $.ajax({
             url: "check.php?last=0",
             success: function(data){
                 //do some stuff
                 checking = setTimeout({listen()}, 3000);
             }
    })
}
             //NOW WHEN USER CLICKS JOIN FOR EXAMPLE-
clearTimeout(checking);
hear.abort();
              //Perform a different ajax call to update db, then resume listen()
```

**CHECK.php**

```
require_once("../abc/connection.php");  // connect to db

//*******START OF VARIOUS TRIED SETTINGS
session_start();
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
session_write_close();
ignore_user_abort(1);      
set_time_limit(40); 
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0); 
ini_set('implicit_flush', 1); 
//*********END OF VARIOUS TRIED SETTINGS

$last = isset($_GET['last']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['last']) : 0 ;
$true = 0;
while($true < 10){
    $true++;
    $str = " ";  //tried this line and below to help force script acknowledgement of ajax abortion
    echo $str;
    if(connection_status() != CONNECTION_NORMAL){
        echo str_repeat($str, 1024);      // In case of minimum output requirement 1KB
        ob_flush();
        flush();
        break;
    }
    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM games WHERE id > $last");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0){
        echo "Change detected";
        break;
    }else{
        mysqli_free_result($sql);
        sleep(3);
    }
}
```

At this point I'm almost ready to revert back to just making the ajax call every 3 seconds. Very grateful for any help. Thanks

Comment: Can you use [`EventSource`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource) then? Sounds like a good choice to me.

Comment: Unrelated to your query, but I would strongly recommend you don't use `mysqli_real_escape_string`.  Look up prepared statements instead, much more secure (https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: @Tigger Thanks for the link, could be the way to go

Comment: @prieber Yes good tip!

Comment: Are you passing in the connection to the query?

Comment: @Vbudo - Good pick up! Yes I am passing in the connection, just a typo I have edited in now. Can't believe there isn't more solid info on this issue

Comment: @Tigger I tried EventSource but it resulted in the same problem

Comment: Maybe you could make a fully reproducible example, so other people could try it and confirm your observation?

Comment: @DarrenCook -  I've seen that enough people have encountered the same problem. A fully reproducible example that works is what I'm after :)

Comment: A minimal fully reproducible example that demonstrates the problem will allow people to try it and tell you what you are doing wrong. Or they will tell you it works for them, that your code is correct, and that the problem is some aspect of your network/setup/browser/etc.  If other people have had the exact same problem, link to their question. Maybe they gave a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example we can debug.

Comment: I'm not going to provide an example with someone else's database. I've stated the situation well enough above. I will add that I've tried the script with other actions which do not include a db query, such as echoing the time after a certain number of loops and this works well without any hang ups or delays. I've also had 2 users query db while I manually update the db and both users receive the updated data immediately. But if user1 or user2 tries to update db whilst also in the query loop themselves, it will not update until the other user's loop has completed its run