# Is SSE and PHP Better than AJAX for chat app?

Tags: php, ajax, chat, server-sent-events, eventsource

I've been reading a lot on the subject of SSE and PHP, most of which seems to be advocating it as viable solutions for all sorts of things including chat apps. I have seen similar questions on this site but have not found a concise, definitive answer.

Is there something inherent in SSE which makes it way more server-friendly than AJAX short polling? Because the headers appear to be of very similar size. I am wondering if there is some kind of behind-the-scenes stuff beyond the headers that a noob like myself can't see e.g. some sort of connection recognition with each request/response? I know there are other factors involved where SSE prevails such as handling disconnections.

In terms of using it in a chat app scenario, ajax and sse appear to be doing the same thing. Neither of them seems to be able to perform long polling effectively with PHP. If I have User A and User B waiting on a PHP script that checks for new messages from the other user in the DB then sleeps for 3 seconds for say 10 loops, User A's new message cannot be inserted until User B has looped through the entire checking script, thereby rendering it absolutely useless (at least based on everything I've tried in the last 2 weeks!). I can get it working smoothly if I chat to myself and no one else is waiting on the checking script, but I've run out of things to talk about with myself and would really enjoy someone else being able to use it too.

So in a nutshell, given an Apache and PHP environment with WebSockets as not an option (due to shared hosting), is the only effective way to write a chat app, based on server burden alone, by short polling with one's choice of either AJAX or SSE, or is SSE definitely the superior option?

I would pursue WebSockets if the eventual traffic called for it and justified the web hosting upgrade.

(ALSO, as a side, is my premise off base regarding the long-polling scenario I described above where User A must wait for User B's loop to finish before he/she/it can perform the insert? Got me confused as to why that should be the case).

Kind of a long-winded, meandering question but hoping someone in the same situation can find this question and save themselves a lot of time.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, SSE is a better option than AJAX, as AJAX polling is done on the main servers, like where most of the normal user traffic is to be hit. Whereas SSE polling is done on another instance which is made for it, so there will be no extra traffic on the main server. Please check Mercure (https://mercure.rocks/)

**EDIT**:

I mean to that, using SSE with platforms like Mercure would be a better option than AJAX. As AJAX will make a request to the main server. Which would increase the count of requests for the main server. Whereas we can distribute the network load using tools like the Mercure, in order to achieve the required functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm not quite sure I understand your answer. Could you elaborate a little?

Comment: Sure,

Fetching data or retrieving data update by SSE is always better options then AJAX.

1) SSE requests are hit on different server (or process within same server). Whereas AJAX requests are hit on main server (or main process such as apache or nginx).

2) Number of request are required more in case of AJAX

Answer (score 1):

SSE can be thought of a thin API wrapper around the AJAX long-poll approach. It brings a standard API to something that was a hacky solution before.

> something inherent in SSE which makes it way more server-friendly than AJAX short polling?

It holds the socket open. The pro of this is less latency (as soon as the server has the new information it sends it to the client, rather than waiting for the next client poll); the con is the extra resource usage (the socket, and the PHP process).

> but I've run out of things to talk about with myself

Surely not. Have you tried starting a chat about if time is an illusion, and what came *before*?

> with WebSockets as not an option (due to shared hosting)

SSE and WebSockets both hold a socket open. Shared hosting ISPs often go round closing sockets that have been open a long time (e.g. over 60s), unless they explicitly say they support SSE. The may also kill long-running PHP processes.

> is my premise off base regarding the long-polling scenario I described above where User A must wait for User B's loop to finish before he/she/it can perform the insert?

I think it is off. The "A" in Ajax is asynchronous, meaning you can have multiple ajax/sse requests running at the same time. And on the server side you will have a distinct PHP process running for each request.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Turns out I have indeed spoken to myself about that very notion of time before time lol! Do these answers remain true for the php sleep loop? Because I just cannot find a way to get it to function smoothly.  I posed the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66770758/php-long-polling-script-not-ending but didn't get an answer to it. Just to clarify, eliminating the php while loop with sleep, empty responses from SSE request every 3 secs are much less overhead than AJAX empty responses every 3secs?